# Strange behaviours with stringWithFormat float

Tags: ios, floating-point, nsstring, lldb

```
(lldb) po [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", 0.01]
(id) $21 = 0x003a2560 19991592471028323832250853378750414848.0
(lldb) po [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", 0.1]
(id) $22 = 0x0de92240 -0.0
```

Does anyone understand the behaviour here? I'm running on device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in `lldb`.  If you try the same thing in `gdb`, it works properly.  I suspect `lldb` is only passing the low 32 bits of the argument.  The IEEE representation of 0.01 and of the number it's printing are these:

```
47ae147b3778df69 = 19991592471028323832250853378750414848.00
3f847ae147ae147b = 0.01
```

Notice that the low 32 bits of 0.01 match the high 32 bits of the other number.

The bug also happens with `printf`:

```
(lldb) expr (void)printf("%.1f\n", 0.01)
19991592257096858016910903319197646848.0
<no result>
```

It doesn't happen with `+[NSNumber numberWithDouble:]`:

```
(lldb) po [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.01]
(id) $3 = 0x0fe81390 0.01
```

So I suspect the bug is in `lldb`'s handling of variadic functions.

You can open a bug report at [the LLVM bugzilla](http://llvm.org/bugs/) and/or at [Apple's bug reporter (aka rdar)](https://bugreport.apple.com/).