# stringWithFormat not working in LLDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, lldb

Why doesn't this work?

```
(lldb) po [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", 1.0]
error: too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

But this does:

```
(lldb) p (void)printf("%f", 1.0)
1.000000
```

Is Objective-C variable arguments syntax not supported in LLDB?

Comment: what is your X-code version ??

Comment: version 5.0 (5A1413).

Comment: Its working proper at my end in xcode 5.0.

Comment: Thanks, Martin R. It's apparently a general LLDB issue with variable argument lists.

Comment: Still not resolved, I am under Xcode 8.3.2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As Martin R pointed out in the comments, it's apparently a [general LLDB issue with variable argument lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19339599/235297).

On the other hand, as [Patrik Schmittat pointed out](https://twitter.com/cipherCOM/status/391162084610031616), `-initWithFormat:` works just fine:

```
(lldb) po [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", 1.0]
1.000000
```

I've filed a radar for this: [rdar://15261415 (stringWithFormat not working in LLDB)](http://openradar.appspot.com/15261415)

Answer (score 2):

```
Basically this is the bug in lldb, if you try the same in gdb it works. 
lldb is only passing the low 32 bits of the argument.
```

Please follow this link [Strange behaviours with stringWithFormat float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372232/strange-behaviours-with-stringwithformat-float)

Also samthing i have tried in GDB and its work fine as attached in the screens shot:-
[image]

Now i tried the samething in GDB:-
[image]

Comment: Hm, but `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"test"]` and `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1]` don't work either. It seems it's a general LLDB issue with variable argument lists.

Comment: yes, even this will also doesn't work

Comment: What are you people running under? Mac 32 bit? iOS 32 bit? Mac 64 bit? Simulator? ... ? Maybe it works on 32-bit OSes?

Comment: Issue occurs on iPhone 5s, 4s and the simulator (32 and 64 bit mode). So it's obviously architecture independent.